# How te get content on node

Tags: c#, xml

I have this code

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"E:\TA\Kompleksitas Algoritma\C#\Dari Buku\ConsoleApplication3\hadits.xml");

        Console.Write("Masukan kata kunci: ");
        string keyword = Console.ReadLine();

        // Get and display all the book titles.
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName("isi");

        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].InnerXml + "\n");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Can you help me, how to get content on node if we have input the keyword ?

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean by "how to get content on node if we has input the keyword". (I'd personally use LINQ to XML as well, but that's a different matter...)

Comment: basically I have an xml file, I want to display the data in the xml but based on the keywords entered in the search

Comment: Show an example xml file and the data you want to retrieve

Comment: "Based on the keywords" is *really* vague. As reggaeguitar says, you should really provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct,

Here is what I've done:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("Your XML");
string keyword = Console.ReadLine();

//Navigate through all IsiNode
foreach (var isiElement in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    if (isiElement.Value.Contains(keyword))
    {
        Console.WriteLine (isiElement.Value);
    }
}
```

To use `XDocument` use System.Xml.Linq

Comment: what's wrong?
"The type or namespace name 'XDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: where I have to put the xml file?
I've tried but still can not "XmlException was unhandles. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Comment: Use XDocument.Load("FilePath")

Answer (score 0):

use Value property:

```
 elemList[i].Value;
```

Comment: you are having the for loop to iterate over the nodes, now to get the value for each node, then use what i wrote above inside the for loop.

Comment: Your answer doesn't sufficiently address the original question, or put it in a context that is usable by the questioner.

Comment: @Ronny: you might want to edit your answer so that it reflects your comments.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg thx but too late, someone already copied the same answer and the awesome author didnt realize that :)